# History.js в мобильных браузерах.

Tags: mobile, ajax, history, javascript

У меня есть сайт, функционирующий полностью на AJAX + History.js. То есть при нажатии на ссылку срабатывает функция:

```
$('a').click(function(){
// загрузка данных через AJAX
return false;
});
```

Будет ли работать такой сайт на мобильных устройствах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будет ли работать та или иная технология в определённых браузерах, можно посмотреть тут: http://caniuse.com/

А если в вкратце, то работать будет! Отвалится только в Internet Explorer 8,9 и Opera Mini, чем можно без тени сомнения пренебречь.